# Showing that $f=0$ a.e. then $\int f=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{M},μ\right)$ be a measure space and f be integrable over $X$ with respect to $\mu$. I want to show that if $f=0$ almost everywhere on $X$ then $\int_{E}fd\mu=0$ for every $E\in\mathcal{M}$.

My attempt: By the Simple Approximation Theorem, there is an increasing sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ of non-negative simple functions that converge pointwise to $f$. Therefore, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem,

$$\int_{E}fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}\phi_nd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_n\int_{E}d\mu = 0\cdot\mu(E) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  cannot pull $\phi_n$ out of the integral since it is not a  constant.

Observe that $f^{+}=\max \{f,0\}=\max \{0,0\}=0$ almost evrywhere. Similarly, $f^{-}=0$ almost everywhere. This allows us to assume that $f$ is non-negative.

There exist non-negative simple functions $\phi_n$ increasing to $f$. It follows that each $\phi_n=0$ almost everywhere. I will let you check that if $\phi$ is simple and $0$ almost everywhere then its integral is $0$. [Use definition of integral for  a simple function]. Now $\int f d\mu=\lim \int \phi_n  d\mu=\lim 0=0$.

Comment: I see. Are you concluding that each $\phi_n=0$ almost everywhere since $0\leq|\phi_n|\leq|f|=0$ on $X$ for all $n$?

Comment: @D.Math Yes, exactly.

Comment: Oh! I didn’t mean to do so. I’ll accept it again. But also, this isn’t a two year old post?

Comment: Sorry, I read the date wrongly. And thanks for restoring the approval.